# Функции с контекстом. Javascript

Tags: javascript, объекты, рефлексия

Есть объект:

```
const button = {
id: "",
class: "",

instance: function () {
    return Object.assign({}, button);
},
setID(id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
},
setClasses(_classes) {
    this.class = _classes;
    return this;
} 
}
```

Вызываю вот так:

```
button.instance()
.setID("button1")
.setClasses("button")
```

В целом, все работает, но есть одна проблема. У меня таких объектов несколько и функции у них повторяются. Как я могу указать, что this в функции не object(button), а тот объект, из которого я вызываю её?

**Приведу пример на классах**: есть три класса classOne, classTwo, classMore. У всех этих классов есть одна и та же функция setTitle(). Вместо того, чтобы прописывать всем классам эту фукнцию **снова и снова**, я решаю её вынести и пишу метод-расширитель:

```
<T>.setTitle(String str) {
    ///this в текущем контексте это класс, который я передаю.
    this.title = str;
}

classOne.setTitle("as");
classTwo.setTitle("as2");
classMore.setTitle("as3");
```

**САМОЕ ГЛАВНОЕ**, я должен получить тот же объект, который "отправлял", чтобы продолжить вызывать мои функции. Реализовать такое в других языках легко, а вот с js, да ещё и с объектами, хз как.

Если вместо `setID(id) {}` пишу `setID: () => {}`, то мне удается передавать контекст, но он уже не возвращается. Т.е., если я сделаю так:

```
button.instance()
.setID('asda')
.render() //уже другая функция объекта
```

То мне вылетает ошибка, мол функции render **не существует**. Как я понимаю, это из-за того, что он теряет контекст. **Что делать?**

Comment: Не понятно откуда взялся render. Вместо рассказа лучше напишите на JS что вы ожидаете, в одно полотно, без перерывов на другие языки. "У меня таких объектов несколько" - где? This у простых методов объекта и так всегда тот объект, от которого вызывается метод. Ещё не понял зачем прописывать метод снова и снова, если можно сделать предка с этим методом.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, render это лишь пример другой функции, которую я могу вызвать после setID и т.п. "Ещё не понял зачем прописывать метод снова и снова, если можно сделать предка с этим методом." - можно тут подробнее? Как мне назначить родителя? Есть примеры?

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, всё ж понятно написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy мне иногда так пишут что всё понятно, но почему-то до того, как я расспрошу, ответов нет. Ну и я не могу от вашего сознания говорить, говорю от своего.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, я от своего ответ написал ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy вот что мне было не понятно: "У меня таких объектов несколько" - объектов как button? "и функции у них повторяются" - написаны в каждый из этих объектов? "Как я могу указать, что this в функции не object(button), а тот объект, из которого я вызываю её" - он и так уже такой. "Приведу пример на классах" - это не JS. "есть три класса classOne, classTwo, classMore" - это не классы. "То мне вылетает ошибка, мол функции render не существует" - её и не существует. "Как я понимаю, это из-за того, что он теряет контекст" - нет, её просто не существует.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, да, интересные моменты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример классов и наследования. Не знаю отвечает это на вопрос или нет.

```js
class Predok {
  predokMethod(){
    this.predokValue = Date.now();
    return this;
  }
}

class Button extends Predok {
  
  constructor(){
    super();
    
    this.id = "";
    this.classes = "";
  }
  
  setID(id){
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }
  
  setClasses(classes){
      this.classes = classes;
      return this;
  }
}

let button1 = new Button().setID("button1").setClasses("button 111").predokMethod();
let button2 = new Button().setID("button2").setClasses("button 222").predokMethod();

console.log(button1);
console.log(button2);
```

Answer (score 1):

В принципе похоже на то, что тебе нужно наследование. Но по описанию тебе достаточно прототипов, а полное наследование реализовывать не требуется.

Если есть объект с неким набором методов:

```
var base = {
  setId(id) {
    this.id = id
    return this
  },
  setOther(other) {
    this.other = other
    return this
  }
}
```

и есть конструкторы, которыми создаются объекты, то перед добавлением методов в их прототип можно присвоить прототипу новый объект, созданный на основе `base`:

```
function Smth(x) {
  this.x = x
}

Smth.prototype = Object.create(base)
```

Если объекты создаются напрямую, то можно положить методы непосредственно в прото объекта. С использованием современного синтаксиса это можно сделать так:

```
var a = {
  __proto__: base,
  y: 2
}
```

А с использованием возможностей ES5 так:

```
var b = Object.create(base)
b.y = 3
```

или так (с созданием временного объекта):

```
var с = Object.assign(Object.create(base), {
  y: 4
})
```

Если объект уже существует, то теоретически сейчас можно поменять ему прототип, но большинство источников рекомендует так не поступать, чтобы не угробить производительность всего, что как-то взаимодействует с этим объектом:

```
var d = { z: 5 }
Object.setPrototypeOf(d, base)
```

А ещё можно докинуть методы в объект как миксины:

```
var o = { u: 6 }
Object.assign(o, base)
```

Кстати, добавление методов как миксинов в прототип конструктора тоже возможно.

## Полный пример со всеми вариантами

```js
var base = {
  setId(id) {
    this.id = id
    return this
  },
  setOther(other) {
    this.other = other
    return this
  }
}

function Smth(x) {
  this.x = x
}

Smth.prototype = Object.create(base)

var s = new Smth(0)

var a = {
  __proto__: base,
  y: 2
}

var b = Object.create(base)
b.y = 3

var c = Object.assign(Object.create(base), {
  y: 4
})

var d = { z: 5 }
Object.setPrototypeOf(d, base)

var o = { u: 6 }
Object.assign(o, base)

function log(obj) {
  console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return key + ": " + obj[key]
  }).join("\n"))
}

log(s.setId('s').setOther(100))
log(a.setId('a').setOther(101))
log(b.setId('b').setOther(102))
log(c.setId('c').setOther(103))
log(d.setId('d').setOther(104))
log(o.setId('o').setOther(105))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```